# convert string to comma during loop in PHP

Tags: php

I want to loop group of data with PHP, but my problem is I want to replace all `semicolons (;)` and line breaks `enterspace` to comma `(,)`. Looping must also start with my comment `(<- Record Start)` & `(record end)`.

Data:

```
P;A251213027;142G;3142831233555;10062014:0420;101;3000.00;0.00; (<- Record Start)
050;0;0;0;N;3000.00;0.00;0.00;Y;;;2PH_02
C;LOIVINO;ICIO
C;1AN INT;MALY;MAR;;;MAL
C;GRSE;LPES
C;B;PHILIPPINES;N0203004177;;Y;12112015;12111977;PHILIPPINES;PHILIPPINES
C;Y;09064656319;DO NOT HAVE;DO NOT HAVE;FRIEND;;
C;
C;;;B125 LO259;QU2TY;;PH (<- End Record)
```

**EDIT**
I Found out where the record must start and end.

Here's my code

```
// break each result set
$parts = explode('C;', $str); 

foreach($parts as $part){
    // C;;; is not in the $parts array, if you want it in the result
    // add it here
    $res = explode(';', $part); 
    foreach($parts as $part){
        // you have each line of the result
    }

}
```

Comment: Try using - str_replace( ';' , ',' , $var)

Comment: I don't get your requirements.  You have multiple `C;` in there, why do some "end the loop" and some don't?

Comment: You have edited your sample second time. Are you sure this is what you want and did you yet try the samples provided by the posters?

Comment: @AT-2016 sorry about that, but this the last edited that im going to make. please see edit above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your data, you don't want to explode on `C;` but on `C;`+`linebreak`. I don't know how wellformed your data is, so let's play it safe: remove spaces, search for all kinds of linebreaks and even something like

```
C;1;2;3;4;5;6;7
C;   <- end_loop
C;   <- end_loop
C;1;2;3;4;5;US
```

First be sure there is a linebreak at the end of the data, and add some kind of *end of data* sign (in this case the underscore `_`):

```
$str.= "\r\n_";
```

Now remove all spaces. And as I don't know what kind of linebreaks you use, replace all kinds of them by some other, easily recognizable character, like `*` and make sure there are no double linebreaks:

```
$str = str_replace (' ', '', $str);  //remove all spaces
$str = str_replace (array('\r\n', '\n', '\r'), '*', $str); //replace all linebreaks
$str = str_replace ('**', '*', $str); //remove double linebreaks
```

then explode on `C;*`, being the end of a data-part:

```
$str= explode( 'C;*' , $str );
```

now for each part you can replace the `;` and the `*` with a comma:

```
foreach($str as $v){
    $new_str[] = str_replace (array( '*', ';' ), ',', $v) . 'C,';
    }
```

One last thing to do as you will end up with an unwanted `_C,` at the end of your array:

```
end($new_str);
$key = key($new_str);
if($new_str[$key]=='_C,'){
    unset($new_str[$key]);
    }
```

Why the `_` at the end of the file? To make sure you can seperate parts with only `C;` in the middle of your file, and the last one at the end of the file.

**[edit]**

Because the actual data differs from the sample given first, a revised answer.

```
$str.="\r\n_";
$str = str_replace (' ', '', $str);
$str = str_replace (array("\r\n", "\n", "\r"), '*', $str);
$str = str_replace ('**', '*', $str);
$str = str_replace ('C;*', '~~', $str);
$str = str_replace (';*', ';', $str);
$str = str_replace ('*', ';', $str);

$str= explode( '~~' , $str );
foreach($str as $v){
   $new_str[] = str_replace (array( '*', ';' ), ',', $v) . 'C,';
   }

end($new_str);
$key = key($new_str);
if($new_str[$key]=='_C,'){
    unset($new_str[$key]);
    }
```

Comment: The actual data differs from the sample you gave. I've edited my answer, it works finenow  and gives the desired output.

Comment: sorry about multiple edited, but i promise this is the last. Please check where the record start and ends. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function something like this.

```
//$str your string with semicolons (;) and new line charecter
preg_replace('/;\s+/', ',', trim($str));
```